# How to request a SecureString password on button click to pass to a Power Shell process

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, passwords

I have an application that runs a command through Power Shell. I know how to run this as a different user, but I am at a complete loss as to how to get the password. I want to prompt the user for the password each time (I only expect the app to be used once at most), so I don't need it to be stored. I understand that I need to create the password as a secure string. On top of this, I want it to run when a button is clicked, but I cannot figure out how to call on this. This is what I have so far:

```
class Credentials  
{
    private static SecureString MakeSecureString(string text)  
    {  
        SecureString secure = new SecureString();  
        foreach (char c in text)  
        {  
            secure.AppendChar(c);  
        }        

        return secure;
    }

    public static void RunAs(string path, string username, string password)
    {
        try
        {

            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe";
            process.StartInfo.UserName = "adminaccount@account.com";
            process.StartInfo.Password = MakeSecureString(password);
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.Start();
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine(" Some Power Shell Script");
            process.StandardInput.Flush();
            process.StandardInput.Close();
            process.WaitForExit();
            Console.WriteLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
            Console.WriteLine(process.StandardError.ReadToEnd());
            Console.Read();
        }
        catch (Win32Exception w32E)
        {
            // The process didn't start.
            Console.WriteLine(w32E);
        }
    }
}

// Later invoked in this button click handler
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Credentials.SecureString();
    Credentials.RunAs();
}
```

How can I have this run when the button is clicked (Button_Clicked). I feel like I understand almost everything, but I am missing something very important.

Comment: Your `Credentials` class doesn't have a `SecureString` method (1st line in `Button_Click`).

Answer (score 0):

The method signature of your `RunAs()` method takes 3 arguments, but in the `Button_Clicked` handler you don't pass any arguments to it - fix that:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = @"C:\path\to\file";
    string username = "User1";
    string password = "Sup3r5eCr37p@s$w0rd";
    Credentials.RunAs(path, username, password);
}
```

I imagine you'll want to grab the values for `path`, `username` and `password` from the text field of UI elements in your form

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the advice.

I was able to bypass all of this by starting the Power Shell Script with 'Get-Credential', which will prompt the user for the password. Much easier (and safer).